# python extract data from html tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I want to extract the (paragraph) within the html tags in Python

```
 &lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&quot;&gt;

 Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive.

 &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

My code is

```
 from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = """&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&  quot;font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&quot;&gt; Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive. &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"""

p1 = HTMLParser()
p1.unescape(x)
bdy_soup = BeautifulSoup(p1.unescape(x)).get_text(separator=";")
print(bdy_soup)
```

this code is not returning anything please help me to do so ,, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you reading it from a html page or a text file?

Comment: @prakash-palnati   --- reading from Sql table

Comment: @s.s you can use  ```BeautifulSoup``` to extract your extact data. first do ```import html >>> html.unescape(x).```

Comment: @manoj jadhav can you  explain the code

Comment: @s.s check my post.

Answer (score 3):

1. use `html.unescape` to convert html char to ascii
2. use `bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_content).text` to extract the content

---

```
>>> x = """&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&quot;&gt; Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive. &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"""

>>> import html
>>> xx = html.unescape(x)
'<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">\n\n Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive.\n\n </span></p>'

>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.BeautifulSoup(xx, "html").text
' Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive. '
```

Comment: this is not working can you please help me explaining the code

Comment: I modified it. @s.s

Comment: i modified my question  please see

Comment: thnks  for your help i posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. please install `HTMLParser` and `beautifulsoup4` first.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
p = "&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;span 
 style=&quot;font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&quot;&gt; Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive. &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
p1 = HTMLParser()
p1.unescape(p)
bdy_soup = BeautifulSoup(p1.unescape(p)).get_text(separator="\n")
print bdy_soup
```

Comment: the text in p = { "&lt;p ......... gt;&lt;/p&gt;" }  showing error

Comment: @s.s what is the exact input? can u put full snippet for input?

Comment: Exactly this===  &lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&quot;&gt;Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: your code is running but not  returning any outPut..what do i have to print..?

Comment: please add ```print bdy_soup```. what you get in ```bdy_soup```

Comment: nothing  that must be because separator is "\n" ... please see this---  &lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&quot;&gt;Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: did you get it ?

Comment: @s.s not getting you. can u please post your code snippest?

Comment: from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = """&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&quot;&gt; Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive. &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"""

p1 = HTMLParser()
p1.unescape(x)
bdy_soup = BeautifulSoup(p1.unescape(x)).get_text(separator=";")
print(bdy_soup)

Comment: i edit my question please see

Comment: thanks manoj your code worked with some small edits ...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the data between two HTML tags

```
r'<title[^>]*>([^<]+)</title>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The code worked by installing lxml parser.. thankyou everyone for your help

 import html
 import bs4
 import html.parser
 import lxml
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 x = """&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&  quot;font-size: small; font-family: lato, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&quot;&gt; Irrespective of the kind of small business you own, using traditional sales and marketing tactics can prove to be expensive. &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"""

 p1 = html.unescape(x) 
 bdy_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(p1, "lxml").get_text(separator="/n")
 print(bdy_soup)
```